# what's the difference between two kinds of iteration of list

Tags: python

Here is my code
i got two different output which are [2] and [2,4,6], can someone do some explanation?

```
list = [1,2,3]
def getdouble(l):
    result = []
    for i in l :
        i = i * 2
        result.append(i)
    return result

print getdouble(list)

def getdouble_v2 (l):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = l[i] * 2
        result.append(l[i])
    return result

print getdouble_v2(list)
```

Comment: I get `[2, 4, 6]` and `[2, 4, 6]`. But the difference is that second one also modifies the original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get the output you claim is if the indentation in your file is broken. Verify that you're not mixing spaces and tabs with `python -tt`.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions return the same `result` list for the same input list. However the second function modifies the original list as well in the line `l[i] = l[i] * 2`. The first function does not.

So, the results for the first function are:

```
l = [1,2,3]
result = [2,4,6]
```

The results for the second function are:

```
l = [2,4,6]
result = [2,4,6]
```

Comment: i wouldn try to run the second one multiple times without re initializing l:)

Comment: @root Indeed, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 4 spaces for indentation except for the line

```
        return result
```

which is indented by a tab. This is unfortunate because your editor shows the tab as 4 spaces, but Python treats it as 8 spaces, so the code looks like this to Python

```
list = [1,2,3]
def getdouble(l):
    result = []
    for i in l :
        i = i * 2
        result.append(i)
        return result
```

So you see, it's returning after the first item is appended to the list